# Better Way to display emails c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, email, listview, imap

hello i have the following code which lets me display the emails in my inbox on a list view control and display the corrospoding body in a rtb my question is there a better way to handle this data and display it than the  way below im pretty new to c# so detailed answers would be great

p.s im using the chilkat imap component to handle the server side if things
Thanks In Advance

```
  Chilkat.MessageSet msgSet = imap.Search("ALL", true);
        bundle = imap.FetchBundle(msgSet);

        Chilkat.Email email;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < bundle.MessageCount - 0; i++)
        {
            email = bundle.GetEmail(i);

            System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem itmp = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(email.From);
            System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem itms1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmp, email.Subject);
            System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem itms2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itmp, email.FromName);


            itmp.SubItems.Add(itms1);
            itmp.SubItems.Add(itms2);

            listView1.Items.Add(itmp).Tag = i;



            richTextBox1.Text = email.Body;





        }

        // Save the email to an XML file
        bundle.SaveXml("email.xml");
```

*Updated Code*

```
 Chilkat.MessageSet msgSet = imap.Search("ALL", true);
        bundle = imap.FetchBundle(msgSet);

        Chilkat.Email email;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < bundle.MessageCount; i++)
        {
            email = bundle.GetEmail(i);

            string[] row = new string[]{email.From,
                                                    email.Subject,email.FromName};


            object[] rows = new object[] { row };
            foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
            {
                listView1.Rows.Add(rowArray);
            }
```

Comment: "my question is there a better way to handle this data and display it than the way below " - what defines 'better'?

Comment: Well i wanted to change from using a list view to using a data grid view or something like that but they wont work with the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think , you are doing correct only small point

```
Put a null check for bundle and email object. 

  for (i = 0; i < bundle.MessageCount - 0; i++)  m, why are you substracting 0 from bundle.MessageCount
```

your code is simple and its doing what it is intended to do so why change at this time.

Comment: Thanks will do, the reason i wanted to change it is cause the list view control itself dosnt look very good and i cannot find a diffrent compnonet to replace it that looks better and works with the above code

Comment: oh that's the problem , what are the different column you want to show in grid , you can refactor this code to support datagrid.

Comment: Edited the code to support the data grid view working fine now thanks for your help